# Unsupervised Naive Bayes - how does it work?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian, naivebayes, unsupervised-learning

So as I understand it, to implement an unsupervised Naive Bayes, we assign random probability to each class for each instance, then run it through the normal Naive Bayes algorithm. I understand that, through each iteration, the random estimates get better, but I can't for the life of me figure out exactly how that works.

Anyone care to shed some light on the matter?

Comment: can you share a reference to the specific algorithm you're referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variant of Naive Bayes in unsupervised learning that I've seen is basically application of *Gaussian Mixture Model* (GMM, also known as *Expectation Maximization* or EM) to determine the clusters in the data.

In this setting, it is assumed that the data can be classified, but the classes are hidden. The problem is to determine the *most probable* classes by fitting a Gaussian distribution per class. Naive Bayes assumption defines the particular probabilistic model to use, in which the attributes are conditionally independent given the class.

From ["Unsupervised naive Bayes for data clustering with mixtures of
truncated exponentials"](https://www.utia.cas.cz/files/mtr/pgm06/56_paper.pdf) paper by Jose A. Gamez:

> From the previous setting, probabilistic model-based clustering is
>   modeled as a mixture of models (see e.g. (Duda et al., 2001)), where
>   the states of the hidden class variable correspond to the components
>   of the mixture (the number of clusters), and the multinomial
>   distribution is used to model discrete variables while the Gaussian
>   distribution is used to model numeric variables. In this way we move
>   to a problem of learning from unlabeled data and usually the EM
>   algorithm (Dempster et al., 1977) is used to carry out the learning
>   task when the graphical structure is fixed and structural EM
>   (Friedman, 1998) when the graphical structure also has to be
>   discovered (Pena et al., 2000). In this paper we focus on the
>   simplest model with fixed structure, the so-called **Naive Bayes**
>   structure (fig. 1) where the class is the only root variable and all
>   the attributes are conditionally independent given the class.

See also [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/70084/130598) on CV.SE.